# Using html control - listbox tag in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I am setting a condition in listbox using jsp code. But it is not working. It does not recognise or accept the value attribute of option tag given in out.print function of jsp.

```html
<td>
  <Select name="lbox" multiple>
    <%
      if(request.getParameter("go")!=null)
      {
        if(request.getParameter("sbox")=="1")
        {
          out.print("<option value="gs">German Shepard</option>");
          out.print("<option value="p">Pug</option>");
          out.print("<option value="l">Labra</option>");
        }
        else if(request.getParameter("sbox")=="2")
        {
          out.print("<option value="ps">Persian</option>");
          out.print("<option value="r">Ragdpll</option>");
          out.print("<option value="b">Bengal</option>");
        }
      }
    %>
  </Select>
</td>
```

If first condition is true, then listbox should display these options:-

```
German Shepherd
Pug
Labra
```

And if second condition is true, then listbox should display these options:-

```
Persian
Ragdoll
Bengal
```

Comment: What does `request.getParameter("sbox")` have in it ,print and check onces .

Comment: Your using captial "S"s for your `select` tags.

Comment: It worked somehow thanks for your help @swati.

Comment: @akaBase i dont think that matters because html is not case sensitive